# SwiftUI - How can set a boundary for elements in ZStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, zstack

In my example image you can see that the "World" text can be moved (drag) outside the image area. It is positioned below the Add Sticker button. This element is in a ZStack. So I don't want my text element to go outside the image area. I tried giving a width and height to the ZStack, but didn't work.

[image: Text higher than the image, but overflowing out of its bounds]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the `ZStack` to clip its children using [the `clipped(antialiased:)` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/clipped(antialiased:)).

```
ZStack {
    ...
}
.clipped()
```

This won't stop the user from dragging the `Text` outside of the `ZStack`'s bounds, but it will stop the outside part of the `Text` from being drawn.

If you don't want to let the user drag the `Text` outside of the `ZStack`'s bounds, you need to edit your question to include the code that implements dragging.